# VBoxVGA works, but VBoxSVGA for VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kubuntu

I am trying to run Windows 7 as a guest in a VirtualBox on my Kubuntu 20.04 host. When I use VBoxVGA as graphic controller, this works. However, I would like to use 3d acceleration; thus, I need VBoxSVGA. However, when I use VBoxSVGA and start the VM I get the error

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: While keeping the settings you want try booting the installation ISO and perform a repair. Don't forget to remove the ISO afterwards.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Do you mean the installation ISO of Windows 7? How do I perform the repair exactly?

Comment: Yes, booting it the same way as you did to install it. How to perform the repair I'm not sure since the last time I used it was almost 15 years ago. Do not use outdated, unsupported OSes, not even in a VM with access to the internet, unless you have to. Needless to say, running outdated, unsupported software that doesn't run in supported versions of the OS is NOT a reason.